# method toArray() not working on a list

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm trying to convert a list to an array, but I get an error and I can't figure out why. I'm taking the current hour and in a for loop I get the rest of the hours of today and put it in a list. When i try to change it to an array I get an error. I try to do this because later I use that array in a `JCombobox`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    //JFrame elements
    private JButton btnSetTime;
    private JLabel lblTitle;
    private JComboBox comboTime;

    //Standard elements
    private Timer tillPopup, tillShutdown;

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    int hour = (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    List times = createDropdown(hour);
    // Convert ArrayList to array which can be used in the combobox
    String[] dropdownElements = times.toArray();

    String[] a = {"a","b"};
    public Frame(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //Labels
        lblTitle = new JLabel("Deze applicatie sluit u computer automatisch af om het energieverbruik te verminderen.");

        //Combobox
        comboTime = new JComboBox(a);
        comboTime.setSelectedIndex(0);

        //Button
        btnSetTime = new JButton("Zet afsluittijd");

        //Timers
        //tillPopup = new Timer(this);
        //tillShutdown = new Timer(this);

        //Add elements to Frame
        add(lblTitle);
        add(comboTime);
        add(btnSetTime);

        //Add actionListeners
        btnSetTime.addActionListener(this);

        setSize(500,300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    private List createDropdown(int hour){
        List availableHours = new List();
        for(int i = hour; i <=24; i++){
            if (i != 24){
                availableHours.add(i + ":00");
            }
            else if(i == 24){
                availableHours.add("00:00");
            }
        }
        return availableHours;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getSource() == btnSetTime){
            Object popupTime = comboTime.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println(popupTime);

        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Frame.java:21: error: cannot find symbol  
String[] dropdownElements = times.toArray();  
                                 ^  
    symbol:   method toArray()  
    location: variable times of type List
```

How do I change the list I get back from the `method createDropdown` to an array and why is what I did wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have imported `import java.awt.*;`, the `List` used is `java.awt.List`. You need to add an import - `java.util.List`.

And please don't use raw type `List`. It's not recommended in newer code to use raw types. Of course you couldn't have noticed it, because `java.awt.List` is a non-generic class. So even compiler wouldn't have given you a warning message.

You should use parameterized type - `List<String>` in your case. Modify your method as:

```
private List<String> createDropdown(int hour){
    List<String> availableHours = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
}
```

You also need to add `import java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: your solution works very well, but I don't understand why I have to put `<String>` behind it. also what is the difference between util and awt `list`. ps. I'm a beginner

Comment: @GertKommer `<String>` represent an actual type parameter. You need to put it because `java.util.List` is generic type. You can learn more on generics from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: @GertKommer Or for a quick basic introduction, I've written a blog post - http://rjcodeblog.wordpress.com/2013/09/28/java-generics-a-basic-introduction/ . That will give you a quick start.

Comment: the `java.util` package version of `List` is for simply holding a collection of items, for any purpose -- not specifically for displaying in a user interface as a widget.  The `java.awt` version is specifically a "widget" for displaying a list of items in a user interface.  I imagine from your variable names that you were purposely using the java.awt version.  But that type of `List` does not have a `toArray` method defined in it.